# How do I create a horizontal scrolling cards carousel?

Tags: css

I am having difficulty creating this. The cards just wrap down to a new line when the screen is resized. I have tried to set the overflow to hidden but that has not helped

[image: Scrolling Cards]

This is what I have so far:

```css
.showcase-section{
  height:40vh;
  text-align:center;
  padding:2rem;
}
.showcase__carousel--container{
  padding:2rem;
  height:30rem;
  width:65%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;

}
.showcase__carousel--content{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.showcase__carousel--item{
  height:15rem;
  width:12rem;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin-left:2rem;
  margin-right:2rem;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase-section">
<h2 style="font-size:3rem;">Showcase</h2>
<div class="showcase__carousel--container">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="font-size:10rem; display:inline-block; float:left;"></i>
  <div class="showcase__carousel--content">
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>

  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-size:10rem; display:inline-block; float:right;"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: First thing that pops my mind is that you should use min-width on showcase section, but it is difficult to solve your problem without some jsfiddle, codepen or something similar...

Answer (score 2):

You can use FlexBox in css. The below code for `.showcase__carousel--content` will prevent appending of content to newline.

You can test the [dynamic nature here](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/OBypXr)

```
.showcase__carousel--content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```css
.showcase-section{
  height:40vh;
  text-align:center;
  padding:1rem;
}
.showcase__carousel--container{
  padding:1rem;
  height:30rem;
  width:65%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;

}
.showcase__carousel--content{
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.showcase__carousel--item{
  height:12rem;
  flex: 0 0 12rem;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  margin:0 1rem;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase-section">
<h2 style="font-size:3rem;">Showcase</h2>
<div class="showcase__carousel--container">
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" style="font-size:10rem; display:inline-block; float:left;"></i>
  <div class="showcase__carousel--content">
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="showcase__carousel--item">
    ..
    </div>

  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" style="font-size:10rem; display:inline-block; float:right;"></i>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I tried your approach. When I resize, the cards become either larger or smaller. The point is to dynamically be able to add additional cards and be able to scroll horizontally left to right. I'll add the JS later to achieve that scrolling action when the user clicks the arrow buttons.

Comment: @Hayden you should have to mention that dynamic nature in your post also. Else, no one will know what you want

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to take a look at [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It's a great tool to easily create slideshows. It also has a function to dynamically add/remove slides.

For smaller devices, you can set how much slides you want to show on the screen.
For example: 4 slides on desktop -> 2 slides on tablet, 1 slide on phone.